# how to set oracle 18.3 variable environment permanently in redhat 6.9

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, oracle-12c, oracle-database

I'm trying to set  oracle variable  environment in my .bashrc file, but Boy!...

> export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   /usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin/sqlplus

currently I need to supply the above lines every time that I run sqlplus in a script or from the terminal. So to fix that I added below lines in my .bashrc file .

`export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin/
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$ORACLE_HOME`

but I'm still getting

`bash: sqlplus: command not found`

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with setting those variables system-wide for all users, I would suggest you to put them in an

```
 /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh
```

to make them system-wide. Besides, you also have to add $ORACLE_HOME/bin to the PATH to make your sqlplus available from shell. Thus the final content of oracle.sh may look like:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/18.3/client64/bin/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib:$ORACLE_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Or put them in an appropriate bash startup file ...